# jQuery accessing next class child

Tags: html, jquery, css, click, parent-child

How can I access .prev or .next class inside menuclass when clicking on .childclass class.

So far I came up with this

```
$(".childclass").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().find('menuclass').children('.next')
});
```

Html logic

```
<div class="parentclass">

<div class="menuclass">

<div class="next"></div>
<div class="prev"></div>

</div>

<div class="childclass">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".childclass").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.parentclass').find('.menuclass .next');
});
```